# Concatenate function calls with a template lambda C++20

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++20

I have a template function that concatenates function calls:

```cpp
template<typename Callable, typename... Callables>
decltype(auto) concat_callable(Callable callable, Callables... callables)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(callables) > 0) {
        return [=]
        <typename... Args>
        (Args&&... args) {
            return callable(concat_callable(callables...)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        };
    }
    else {
        return callable;
    }
}
```

I have the following functions that I want to call:

```cpp
std::string& f_1(std::string& str)
{
    return str;
}

std::string& f_2(std::string& str)
{
    return str;
}

std::string& f_3(std::string& str)
{
    return str;
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```cpp
std::string str{ "sample text" };
concat_callable(f_1, f_2, f_3)(str);
```

which is equivalent to:

```cpp
f_1(f_2(f_3(str)));
```

but currently I am getting an error `'std::string &(std::string &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string &'`.

From some reason, it compiles fine when I use only two functions e.g.:

```cpp
concat_callable(f_1, f_2)(str);
```

Any ideas how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-> decltype(auto)` as trailing return type to lambda. Without this, reference from return type is discarded.

```
    return [=]
    <typename... Args>
    (Args&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
        return callable(concat_callable(callables...)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    };
```

Invocation `concat_callable` with `f1`,`f2` can be translated:

```
conact_callable(f1,f2)
    return f1(f2)
```

This works fine, `f1` takes `string&`, `f2` returns reference.

But with three or more callables:

```
concact_callable(f1,f2,f3)
    return f1( concat_callable(f2,f3) )

    /*
    here is a problem because concat_callable discards reference
    from return type and temporary string cannot be bound to
    Lvalue reference.
    */
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oeYWWM53v)